# Hibernate envers: how to get the current audited table name?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers, auditing, spring-data-envers

With Hibernate Envers, is it possible to get the current audited table? I took the example from the [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#configuration) but I add an extra column `tableName`:

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(ExampleListener.class)
public class ExampleRevEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {
    private String username;
    private tableName;
    ...
}
```

And the listener:

```
public class ExampleListener implements RevisionListener {

    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        ExampleRevEntity exampleRevEntity = (ExampleRevEntity) revisionEntity;
        ...
        exampleRevEntity.setUsername(...);

        exampleRevEntity.setTableName(...); // How to get the current table audited table?

    }
}
```

I found this old post [Get audit table name from hibernate envers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48827478/get-audit-table-name-from-hibernate-envers) but without a relevant answer. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`EntityTrackingRevisionListener`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/EntityTrackingRevisionListener.html) which is the extension of the `RevisionListener`.

```
    public class ExampleRevEntityListener
                 implements EntityTrackingRevisionListener {
        @Override
        public void entityChanged(java.lang.Class entityClass, java.lang.String entityName, 
           java.io.Serializable entityId, RevisionType revisionType, java.lang.Object revisionEntity) {

            Table tableAnnotation = entityClass..getAnnotation(javax.persistence.Table.class).name();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.

Comment: I gave a try but this is not enough because many entities could be involved in the same transaction. With this solution only the last table is taken. I have to look for another solution.

Comment: It should be called for all the audited entities. how many entities are persisted in the transaction?

Comment: Sure it is called for all audited entities but only the last one is captured. It's a normal behaviour I think. In my case, 3 entities are involved and the last one wins.